What implications did the new pictures of M87* and Sgr A* had in philosophy in terms of determinism/indeterminism?
I don't know where to correctly and successfully search for this so I hope someone here can lead me the right way. (Also worth noting that my knowledge of physics is equal to zero)
When the polarized pictures of both M87* and Sgr A* were taken it was said that they could show that Einstein was right with his theory of General Relativity (?) and also how the Hawking Radiation theory could also be right (?)
Given that Einstein's theory is a deterministic one and Hawking's theory is not, what implications did those pictures have regarding the deterministic universe/indeterministic universe?
I hope I make sense and that I'm not just saying nonsense.
Thanks in advance.

This sounds like a question for a physicist, not a philosopher. But there's plenty of support for general relativity already and it's already widely-accepted because of that (regardless of whether this is another piece of evidence). Also, the determinism vs indeterminism thing you're describing here sounds like a potentially-not-particular-accurate allusion to the black hole information paradox (but I can't really say much about that).

My understanding is that GR isn't known to be deterministic in general, and in some cases it's known to be nondeterministic, i.e., in some cases it's known that the Einstein field equations, with a given initial condition, have more than one solution. See Chrusciel-Isenberg's 1993 paper "Non-isometric vacuum extensions of vacuum
maximal globally hyperbolic spacetime" for this. It's LOCALLY deterministic, at least if the initial conditions are smooth (proven by Choquet-Bruhat in the 1952 paper "Theoreme d’existence pour certains systemes d’equations
aux derivees partielles non lineaires").

Thank you all for the answers, I'll make sure to take a good look on the mentioned sources. I did in fact think that this question would be better for a physicist but, since the underlining question was on the philosophical implications I thought it would fit well here too. Once again, thank you :)

It is not empirical theories that are deterministic or indeterministic but rather their interpretations. Classical mechanics is 'deterministic' in the popular view, but that is not so, see indeterminism in classical mechanics. Similarly, the 'indeterministic' quantum mechanics has deterministic interpretations (Bohm, MWI). So no empirical findings will have direct implications for determinism, they can be interpreted either way. Perhaps, they could make one or the other more plausible taken overall, but just two pictures won't do much.

I understand what you mean, I will take a look at the link you sent in the morning, thank you all once again! The provided ressources were a great help (still need to look into them completely and with a good set of eyes).

Please edit the question to at least mention what M87* and Sgr A* are and why the pictures of them might be relevant to the issue of general relativity. Casual readers should not have to resort to a search engine to have an idea what you are asking about.

@BernardoPiedade Please post your question on the physics site https://physics.stackexchange.com/

I comprehend that and I appreciate every input I received on this. Following up on your comment (@JD) could you present me with a the right place to ask this question in order for me to receive the most appropriate answer and route to follow?

Well, given Conifold's insights, it's my belief that this is a tough question for either physics or philosophy and that cross-posting is the best strategy. Understanding what constitutes causal determinism (SEP) is a highly philosophical topic and I'm not sure how the folks at physics will serve up an understanding of it (though for all I know they have some maestros). I'm simply arguing that any questions about causality which is a metaphysical topic are probably better answered here, so the post should remain open.

Some other links that might be useful from the SEP: Causation in Physics, Probabilistic Causation, Copenhagen Interpretation, Early Interpretations of GR, and Quantum Gravity. I don't have a lot interest in the philosophy of physics, but leaving the question open might allow some people who know to comment.

This may be of interest to you. https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/news/m87-one-year-later-proof-persistent-black-hole-shadow

Once again, thank you very much ^-^. I'll make sure to study those articles and further pages they send me to. I cannot thank you enough!

M87* and Sgr A* are the names given to the black holes located at the centers of two galaxies: M87 (which contains M87*) and our own Milky Way galaxy (which contains Sgr A*).
Ultrahigh-resolution photographs of both objects were compared with computer simulations of what the black holes should look like based on the equations of General Relativity (GR), and the matches in both cases were quite good. This gave the researchers confidence that both black holes were well-described by GR.
Given the gigantic sizes of both black holes (which makes any Hawking radiation from them exceedingly weak), their distance from Earth, and the overwhelming presence of extremely powerful radiation surrounding both of them, there is no way to detect Hawking radiation from either of them.
The physics of Hawking radiation is every bit as deterministic as the physics of GR. In any case, the black hole images discussed here have absolutely no implications or bearing on any philosophical issues, including whether or not the universe as a whole is deterministic.

+1 for the effort to decrypt the "M87* and Sgr A*" unknowns... in what sense black holes are relevant for philosophy? Why do not redirect the OP to Physics SE?

@MauroALLEGRANZA because I am a regular on the physics SE, currently ranked #8 for the year. I lurk here as a no-cost convenience to answer physics questions on those occasions when they arise. -NN

+1 There seems to be utter confusion by several contributors as to the relationship between comological theories and in/determinism. Thanks for hanging around an interjecting your physics knowledge from time to time.

I forgot to answer, I'm sorry! Thank you for the clarifications. That, plus the other contributors answers have been giving me a really good insight on this matter! I really really appreciate it.
