What is the value of facts in philosophy?
Multiple times my answers here have been downvoted despite being factually correct. It appears to me that "factually correct" is not the same thing as "philosophically correct".
Seems like the opinions of respected philosophers are held in higher regard than actual facts. The actual facts that I have presented have been falsely accused of being mere opinions (of a non-respected non-philosopher).
What am I missing here? Is philosophy all about opinions and the only thing that matters is whose opinions they are? I have always thought that philosophy is supposed to explain the facts, not to challenge them. Science has the responsibility of challenging facts and replacing them with more accurate facts.
Please explain, what is the relation between philosophy and facts?

Seems to be more meta (though the philosophy is interesting it itself)

Facts are relevant: both in everyday life as well as in science? Are they relevant also for philosophy? I would say YES, but... have you ever seen a pair of philosophers agreeing on something? Philosophy is the struggle of opinions.

"philosophy is supposed to explain the facts, not to challenge them." Not exactly: science explains facts; philosophy challenges opinions.

Could you give examples of "actual facts" that were factually correct but philosophically incorrect? And one of philosophy's responsibility is to challenge "facts", by which people often mean their preferred interpretations, which is a big part of explaining why different people have different "facts".

Well, if you're asking about your most recent answer https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/117805/what-implications-did-the-new-pictures-of-m87-and-sgr-a-had-in-philosophy-in-t/117810#117810 I can't say for sure why somebody downvoted it (wasn't me) but my guess would be that you're speaking in general about determinism and not specifically answering what the question was asking, which was how a single observation of M87* could affirm both a deterministic and a non-deterministic theory at the same time.

Are we playing the game "Who is wrong on the internet"? If not, then why care about upvotes or downvotes? If we are (we cannot really avoid it probably), or if you care nevertheless (which is fine), then it may be better to come armed with a hint of an argument plus some references when participating, rather than repeating emphatically (1) determinism is false and (2) there cannot be life in a deterministic universe. I disagree with several people on this forum, in various ways, but can still learn from them if they give some references or a sketch of an argument.

When someone tells you what you're saying isn't facts, and your post is downvoted, it doesn't really make sense to conclude people don't care about facts. When you present what you think are facts, but someone else says it's not, the challenge is to figure out where the disagreement is and why, to provide a justification for what you're saying, but also to sincerely, and with an open mind, listen to the other person, and reflect on the possibility that you're wrong.

I earlier suggested that this question belongs to meta. Now with so many answers (to the philosophical part) I am changing that suggestion somewhat: Split the question into two: the philosophy question here; the meta question there. They an point to each other of course

VTC because this isn't about philosophy. As for votes up or down, for the whole of SE they have only limited relevance to facts. For sure you're likely to be downvoted if your question is factually wrong, but it could also be related to how easy it is to find answers online, how closely it matches the group mission, how well you wordsmithed it, or simply how interesting the question is to people. Ditto answers.

my answers here have been downvoted despite being factually correct An answer can be factually correct and still be a poor answer.

I think this is more a question for meta.
But treating it as here, I'd say you may find Gurdjieff's 3 way classification useful
Philosophy, Theory, Practice
A more modern version would be philosophy, science, tech/engineering.

Technology/engineering practice is understanding at our level, as how to more than what is
Science/theory is in terms of laws, the more quantitative, the better
Philosophy is an exploration of all possibilities

Since there is in principle nothing more inclusive than philosophy the fact(!) that we are stating an opinion needs to be more reified.
Just as the foundation of a building is not part of the building in the sense of being not being visible, yet is more part of it than any visible part in the sense that the building wouldn't stand without it, in the same way science is based on assumptions that are not scientific but metaphysical or pre-scientific.
A scientist does not need to state these assumptions without falling outside of science — Mauro calls them opinions:
Oh you believe in homoeopathy?! That's quackery!
A philosopher (more often) needs to.
Ah you believe in homoeopathy? You know that is not in consonance with established basic science eg. the atomic theory right?
This is why science, cloaked in the façade of factive language seems more factual than philosophy which seems speculative, hermeneutic, indeterminate. This is only because the assumptions have been factored out into one place and then become so implicit that it was forgotten they were always assumptions.
The situation is cleanest in math. On the 1st page of many math books, or even on the inside cover we would find: These are the notations and definitions we will use

If you disagree, this is a good time to close the book
If you agree the rest will follow necessarily and inexorably


This seems a very narrow idea of science, mostly applicable to part of physics.

@JackAidley "This"?? Which this are you pointing  to?

"Science/theory is in terms of laws, the more quantitative, the better"

@JackAidley What about medicine? From the prosaic details of pathological tests many of which were formulated in the last few decades, to cutting edge genetic studies, it seems (to me at least) that anything heralded as a great progress is always an increase in "quantitativeization". What counterexample would you cite?

The term/concept of 'laws' in physics is somewhat historical.  Too many physical 'laws' have been found to be non-universal.  We don't talk about the laws of general relativity or Pauli's exclusion law. It's a little pedantic to call this out in casual conversation but when describing science, it seems like a poor choice.

Nice and deep answer, although the last part with math, left me puzzled.

Tnx @IoannisPaizis. The math part put more conceptually is that you get a kind of 'brief trailer' — at least notationally and terminologically — of what you are getting into before spending days and weeks

@JimmyJames Yes there are many synonyms for law (in science) — principle, rule, theory...  The homonymic overlap with legal law is an interesting question in its own right. In sanskrit there is no such overlap — dharma is internal law; karma is external law; ritam is cosmic law

Let's be clear that the term 'fact' wears a lot of hats in these discussions, and it's important to distinguish between them. 'Fact' can mean, variously:

Ontological/metaphysical truth: physical laws are facts of the universe
Momentary observations: I saw a horse on Main Street, that's a fact
Deeply-held beliefs: it is a fact in Christianity that God exists
Commonly-held opinions: People are greedy, that's just a fact of life

What people often fail to understand about both science and philosophy is that these activities are a trajectory from momentary observations towards ontological/metaphysical truths, passing through general opinion and deep belief.
The first thing we should recognize is that simple facts (momentary observations) are fundamental units that are effectively devoid of meaning. If I say "I saw a horse on Main Street", there is no immediate reason to believe that's a false statement, but… what of it? Am I trying to suggest that's unusual? Do I think you were looking for a horse? Do I just happen to like horses? The observation in itself has no meaning until it is combined and integrated with other observations.
The material sciences take simple observations about physical objects and tries to integrate them into theories about the behavior of physical objects. Philosophy takes simple observations of human thought and activity and tries to integrate them into philosophies about the behavior of human beings. In both cases the way we elevate beyond opinion or belief is through more sophisticated and comprehensive integration. The difficulty is that philosophical 'facts' (in the sense of simple observations) are what Durkheim called 'social facts': regularities of behavior and activity that are far more difficult to grasp and quantify than physical properties.

+1 "Momentary observations" Might benefit from broadening to empirical results. We certainly observe literally frequently, but science often treats the term "observation" to encompass all sorts of empirical witnessing and judgement.

The last 2 of your 4 examples have problems and use the word "fact" wrongly (3rd example) or fail to qualify the fact around sufficient language "4th example".    It is a BELIEF within the christian church, not a fact, that GOD exists (it however may still be a fact outside philosophical speculation to the contrary).  For #4, SOME people are greedy is sufficient to state as a fact, but ALL is implied without this qualifier.

@MarkRosenblitt-Janssen: These are the ways the term 'fact' is conventionally used. You don't have to agree with them, but have enough perspective to see that there are points of contention.

Convention shouldn't dictate proper use of words, if convention is causing confusion or inefficient speech.  The word "fact" for example, is causing confusing.
A better word may be "predicate" or "statement".  "I saw a horse on the street":  is it  about the speaker seeing a horse (perhaps hallulcinating) or a fact about the universe regardless of whether the speaker saw it?

There is no fundamental difference between science, philosophy and the conversation with the bartender: They all involve assuming facts; they all involve some reasoning; they all require their participants to have a logical capacity.
People can agree on the conclusion of a reasoning if they agree on the premises (i.e., what are the facts), but not all scientists agree for example on the theory of quantum physics, so they have to disagree at least on some facts (assuming these people are all logical).
There are differences between science, philosophy and everyday disputation, but it is a difference of degree. Scientists are less permissive, indeed much less permissive, than philosophers and than other people as to what the facts are.
Scientists are also able to arrive at a very large consensus (among themselves) as to what the facts are, while philosophers tend to agree mostly with themselves, at least as to some fundamental facts. The reason for this is not that philosophers are inherently irrational or incapable of understanding each other but that they tackle problems which are inherently much more difficult and much less easily circumscribed. For example, unlike philosophers, scientists do not even bother with the so-called hard problem of consciousness.
So your problem might just be that what you think are the facts is not what other people here think what they are because the facts which are relevant to philosophy are sometimes extremely difficult to recognise.

"For example, unlike philosophers, scientists do not even bother with the so-called hard problem of consciousness." - I don't think that this is necessarily true.  I think that most scientists would say that there is no such problem (which contrasts with acknowledging a problem, but not "bothering with it").  As an analogy, I might ask "why is the sky [some_color]?"  Instead of "bothering with" explaining why the sky is [some_color], one could simply say "it's not that color".

Possibly there are better examples

@Him "it's not that color" Sorry, I don't understand what your point is. - 2. "most scientists would say that there is no such problem" Possibly but that's just absurd. I like to believe that most intelligent scientists would say that this is a not a scientific problem, which amounts to not bothering with the problem that there is.

From wikipedia: "In the philosophy of mind, the hard problem of consciousness is to explain why and how humans and other organisms have qualia, phenomenal consciousness, or subjective experience. It is contrasted with the "easy problems" of explaining why and how physical systems give a (healthy) human being the ability to discriminate, to integrate information, and to perform behavioral functions such as watching, listening, speaking..." I think that most scientists would claim that the "easy problems" are the only actual problems

Viz., once we "explain why and how physical systems give a (healthy) human being the ability to discriminate, to integrate information, and to perform behavioral functions such as watching, listening, speaking...", then we have explained all that there was that needed explaining.  Many scientists would claim that the other things, "qualia, subjective experience, etc" are, in reality, just vague notions that, when properly defined, would boil down to just the "easy problems".

So, in response to "why and how humans and other organisms have qualia, phenomenal consciousness, or subjective experience?", one might answer "they don't" or "the assertion that humans have these things isn't even wrong"

Well, ... as @Jo Wehler wrote, "Facts are events which happen in reality", but what is reality? who defines it and why is it so difficult to agree upon what constitutes reality? No one is entitled of having the whole picture, we see fragments of things, the connections are invisible and subjective, everything flows underneath our radars and we try to put marks in order to navigate. But even these marks are fictitious, fabrications of our desire to stabilize the continuous flow of creation, to conquer, to submit, to avoid the unavoidable. Unfortunately our civilization is a result of a (socially engineered) consensus (:history is written by the winners) in all fields: politics, religion, science etc. and polarization is the fuel of evolution ... be happy to participate, be happy to go against the flow, be happy to be ...

Did you really mean "result of a consensus"?

@Jo Wehler, I use consensus as opposed to reasoning, logic, dialectic etc.

@Jo Wehler, I realized your objection, please see edited answer.


First, facts and philosophy belong to different categories: Facts are
events which happen in reality, while philosophy like science try to
describe and explain facts.

Secondly, both disciplines should support their claims with
arguments, not stating a personal opinion without any argument.
What counts as a valid argument is different in philosophy and
science. But in general, it is not enough to just quote some other
person. At least there should be a precise reference to some paper or
book, where one can find the argument of the quoted person.



I do not agree that philosophy tends to explain the facts. I would rather say that merely philosophy concentrates on human values and explores thinking process in general, which btw is also some kind of fact, but instead focused on human perception and not on "objective/independent reality". I.E. science and philosophy goes in radically different directions. Oh, and btw I like science very much.

Difference between science and philosophy is best concentrated in this famous saying "If tree falls in the forest where nobody listens,- Does it produce a sound ?". Science would say yes, because presumably there is an air in the forest and falling tree produces air pressure wave which invokes sound. In philosophy it doesn't matter IF nobody is there in the forest who would be capable to know what sound is and be able to detect it. In this respect falling tree in the vacuum or in the air makes no difference, because there is no one which could find the difference either.

@AgniusVasiliauskas The waves of the air are not sound. Only if there is an observer then they experience the air waves as sound. Sound is the subjective experience of the objectives air waves. Without an observer there is no sound - even if the whole forest crashes.

@AgniusVasiliauskas To your first comment: Plato’s philosophical theory of forms wanted to explain why things and human behaviour have certain qualitative properties. And his theory of anamnesis wanted to explain how we recognize these properties.

Sadly, but sound IS longitudinal pressure waves propagation in the air at least, not depending if somebody hear it or not. That's the science view which also can't be ignored by philosophy. But I do understand basic premise of your argument. I always try to look from different perspectives of the story. What you mean can basically be related to Anthropic_principle which says that we are such and such only because universe is such and such.

@Agnius Vasiliauskas I follow the second sentence of your source: "In human physiology and psychology, sound is the reception of such waves and their perception by the brain." - While you follow the first sentence "In physics, sound is a vibration that propagates as an acoustic wave through a transmission medium such as a gas, liquid or solid." - Hence let's first find agreement which meaning to take.

Yes definitions are different and preferable usage depends on the context. That being said I personally find a first definition awkward,- if sound is just a thing percepted by human brain, then what about animals who also does hear a sound ? Or what about a microphones which are widely used by singers in the concerts,- if they do not register and amplify a sound with sound amplifier system,- what do they do? In addition I have recently read that scientists have created "sound laser" prototype, which definitely,- IF directed to your body,- will be felt instantly without the help of your ears.

If you would like to take a philosophical approach, you cannot start with assumptions. It isn't clear what a fact is - none of the definitions suggested so far is beyond challenge. Consequently, it isn't clear what "factually correct" would be.
Ask a dictionary what a fact is and you will find that it is something like a true statement. But that has merely shifted the problem onto the question of what "true" is. And there is no general philosophical agreement on that. Many whole books have been written on theories of truth.
One might argue that the only assertions that are beyond challenge are logical and mathematical. There again, many philosophers would say that logical and mathematical statements are not truths they are merely the result of symbol manipulation according to agreed rules.
And some would argue that "true" is essentially redundant. To say that a statement is true does no more than to assert the statement.
Another tack would be to talk about correspondence with reality. That is a whole class of theories of truth. But "reality" is just as problematic as any of the other terms. If pursued, it has a tendency to turn out to be something metaphysical. Kantian philosophers (and Wittgenstein) say that we can say nothing about it at all.
Really, there is no finally decisive way to settle matters. It is a question of agreement.

Welcome! Be sure to read https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help to get familiar with "the guidance". :D


Multiple times my answers here have been downvoted despite being factually correct. ... The actual facts that I have presented have been falsely accused of being mere opinions.


What am I missing here?

"The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result."
"You keep saming when you ought to be changing
What's right is right, but you ain't been right yet"
Here is some examples to help you along:

Multiple times my answers here have been downvoted

This is a fact.

despite being factually correct

This is an opinion.
Not so difficult to distinguish, really. Everyone else can do it.

Facts exist. Are you saying they do not?

Maybe read my answer, it might contain a hint.

No, it doesn't. It contains your opinion that the what he presented is not fact.

You are the worst. You have no actual arguments against anything I have posted here. You have only your personal hatred and that is not a good philosophy. Nobody gets any wiser.

The replies you got to your answers taken together could fill a small book, and you discarded them. You don't want arguments, you never listen, you only seek confirmation.and you won't get it here.

A fact can be proven in accord with its definition, however, the issue that erupts is in the matter of acknowledging the definition as being fixed. One of the most common debates that erupts in matters of philosophy is that all definitions are nothing but an irrelevant semantic game. This game is one that rarely if ever is played by all individuals that come across the information, mainly because there is always the probability that one may exercise an argument against the terms, in rejection of the entire argument itself. The idea is that we cannot prove what any word means, yet in the formulation, there are still words that are exercised to try and prove that we cannot prove words and their meaning. Thusly, what would the point of the formulation even be? Obviously, nothing.
Even if this fact is acknowledged, those within the argument or even just discussion, could reject the fact, in support of a "counter fact." Could be as such:

The fact of the matter is not in regard to the substance being greater or lesser in regard to words and their meaning, rather, it is that we simply cannot judge what the weight of a term, even fact, is.

Facts are nothing but subjective, which implies that two facts may always contradict one another, while still attending to objectivity.


Truly, one thing that should be understood is that philosophy and logic are one and one. Logic itself is dealing with matters of fact and proving the facts via proofs and different formulations throughout variation. Within logic, we do even see that different "forms" cater to opinion more so than fact. You could then argue that the opinion is a fact, for it is a fact that the opinion is an opinion. The biggest issue that lies here is that the definition of fact and opinion conflict. Thusly, the paradigm, which is circular, does indeed manifest. This can of course result in "conflicts" within argument or even just conversation, that only perpetuates disagreement.
In conclusion, we see that philosophy is more than compatible with objective facts, while also being doused with a plethora of opinion, that perpetuates conversation that is not always compatible with solutions. Of course, logic is intended to be exercised with the end of a solution, that is true and not false. For solutions themselves are supposed to be effective, and truth is literally the acknowledgment of whether or not something is effective or ineffective.
